# Lubuntu on mac retina display

Tags: lubuntu, macbook

Lubuntu desktop looks so small. Fonts, window panels and the mouse are all small in size because of the mac retina display. What can I do to adjust Lubuntu perfectly on retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Unity Tweak Tool

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open it, click on Fonts and increase the Text scaling factor. You should see the improvement immediately. Explore the other parts of the Unity Tweak tool to further improve your experience.

Comment: Are you sure the unity-tweak-tool  will work on LXDE (as used in Lubuntu)?

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure. I now realize I ignored the L. Why not try it though?